# how to retrieve data in database and output it in a dynamic text box in flash?

Tags: sqlite, flash

I can already retrieve data's from sqlite database to list component in flash but i want to retrieve the data and put it in a dynamic text box. 
Here's my code inserting data.

```
b_new.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, createNew);

function createNew(MouseEvent):void
{
    if(fname.text !="")
    {
        var stat:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
        stat.sqlConnection = connection;
        stat.text = "INSERT INTO user (fname, dateplayed, timein) VALUES (@fname, @dateplayed, @timein)";
        stat.parameters["@fname"] = fname.text;
        stat.parameters["@dateplayed"] = dateplayed.text;
        stat.parameters["@timein"] = timein.text;
        stat.execute(-1, new Responder(selectItems));
        fname.text = dateplayed.text = timein.text = "";
        nulll.text = "";
    }
    else
        nulll.text = "Enter Username!!!"

}
```

and here's how to retrieve it and put it in list component

```
function selectItems(SQLEvent):void
{
    b_save.enabled = false;
    b_delete.enabled = false;
    var stat:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
    stat.sqlConnection = connection;
    stat.text = "SELECT idd, fname, dateplayed, timein FROM user ORDER BY idd";
    stat.execute(-1, new Responder(onSelected));
}

function onSelected(evt:SQLResult):void
{
    if (evt.data != null)
    {
        itemList.dataProvider = new DataProvider();
        for (var i:int=0; i<evt.data.length; i++)
        {
            itemList.addItem({label:(evt.data[i].fname + " " + evt.data[i].dateplayed  + " " + evt.data[i].timein), data:evt.data[i]});
        }
    }
}
```

now I'm trying to retrieve the data and put it in a dynamic text field

```
function selectItems(SQLEvent):void
{
    var stat:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
    stat.sqlConnection = connection;
    stat.text = "SELECT idd, fname, dateplayed, timein FROM user ORDER BY idd";
    //i know this is not the right syntax but this is my algorithm i guess
    do while{
    .read
    name.text = .item(1)
    //something like this
    }
}
```

is there something i could do to make it right? Hope you could help me. Thanks in advance.